# Pydantic TypeError: validate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

This is my `JsonFeedOptions` class.

```py
class JsonFeedOptions(BaseModel):
    address: Optional[AddressType] = None
    signer: Optional[Union[AccountAPI, str]] = None
    Type: Optional[FeedType] = None
```

And I'm trying to validate the data like this.

```py
opts = {"signer": "abcd"}

options = JsonFeedOptions.model_validate(opts)
```

But got this error

```bash
>           options = JsonFeedOptions.model_validate(opts)
E           TypeError: validate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: There no call nor definition of `validate` here.  Where does it come from?  Are you sure this is supposed to be called as a class method, and not as an instance method?

Comment: That's why I'm confused myself. Why it's there

Comment: Here are all the types https://paste.pythondiscord.com/JIWQ

Comment: That's exactly one type, which has nothing to do with your post.  Where is `BaseModel` from?

Comment: Pydantic's BaseModel

Answer (score 1):

Which Pydantic version do you use? You can check this by `pip list` and review the library version (do not forget to activate virtual environment if you have one)

The error `TypeError:` BaseModel.validate() `takes 2 positional arguments, but 3 were given` is relevant to the difference between Pydantic versions 1 and 2.

In Pydantic version 2, the method signature for BaseModel.validate() has been modified, which may lead to this error.

In any case, you cannot touch the Pydantic library method, but you have two options defined [here.](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/)

Option 1: Migrate your code to new Pydantic version
Option 2: Use the old version with from `pydantic.v1 import BaseModel` instead of `from pydantic import BaseModel`. Keep in the mind that this v1 call is possible if you have new version.